# NoModuleFound Error even when I install the module

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I am trying to import some libs, including:

```
from past.builtins import xrange
```

problem is, I keep getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'past'
```

I've successfully installed and upgraded future, both localy AND on my virtualenv:

```
C:\Users\JON>pip install future
C:\Users\JON>pip install --upgrade future
(.env) C:\Users\JON>pip install future
(.env) C:\Users\JON>pip install --upgrade future
```

still, when I run this import on Jupyter I get the error above.
I should mention I'm using Windows 10 and Anaconda+Jupyter for python 3.6

Anybody has an idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this help https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/ ?